# Loop Variable Error - "For" loop's index cannot use a string value

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am using a For Loop inside a Function and I am getting the following error -

"For" loop's index cannot use a string value

even though the Loop variable LookbackCounter is declared as an Integer

```
    Check_Conditions(CondCounter,Timeframe,RefType,RefPrm1,RefPrm2,RefPrm3,RefShift,NomType,NomPrm1,NomPrm2,NomPrm3,NomShift,NomBuffer) =>

    float RetValue = 1.00000
    
    OpenVal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Timeframe, open)
    HighVal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Timeframe, high)
    LowVal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Timeframe, low)
    CloseVal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Timeframe, close)
    VolumeVal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Timeframe, volume)
    
    int LookbackCounter = 0

    if RefType == "RSI"
        RSIValue = ta.rsi(CloseVal, int(RefPrm1))
        for LookbackCounter = 0 to LookBack[CondCounter]
            array.set(RefVal,LookbackCounter,RSIValue[LookbackCounter + RefShift])
            array.set(RefValPrv,LookbackCounter,RSIValue[LookbackCounter + RefShift+1])
        RetValue := RSIValue
    RetValue
```

Comment: LookbackCounter is an int but LookBack[CondCounter] seems to be a string. you can try casting that to an int by doing this int(LookBack[CondCounter])

but I don't know LookBack[CondCounter] is or even if its returning a number.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply -

LookBack[CondCounter] declaration is a global declaration as below
  var LookBack = array.new_int(41)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own problem.

In this line

```
for LookbackCounter = 0 to LookBack[CondCounter]
```

LookBack[CondCounter] is the problem. It is a series integer not a simple integer which causes the error.

I resolved the problem by passing the value to the function as a simple integer rather than referencing the global series integer.